# New Salesforce BUG Winter '19: Some Report Charts do not render on Homepage anymore

Tags: reporting, lightning-experience, bug, report-chart, lightning-home-page

We have created some reports using cumulative line charts. They did run and render fine in Summer '18.

Now in Winter '19 the Report Charts (Standard Salesforce Lightning Components) are blank.

[image]

It show lots of ugly JS errors in the console:

[image]

Clicking on "View Report" link it works in the "Enhanced Run Page (Beta)":

[image]

BUT not it the "Legacy Run Page":

[image]